# Extracting data from new report and compiling specific data to one excel sheet

Tags: vba

Hello I am trying to create a VBA code where I could automate extracting specific data from new reports and placing them into a home excel sheet. I am using Application.getopenfilename to locate the file but am having issues with errors when i run my code. I get a mismatch error when I try to use For i = 1 To UBound(FileNames)

I have already tried changing the dim i to integer but it didn't work

```
Sub AutomateReport()
Dim FileNames As Variant
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("A1").Select
FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename("top 20(*.xlsx)),*.xlsx", ".xlsx", "Insert Latest Top 20 Report", "Import", MultiSelect = True)
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To UBound(FileNames)
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book1.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    Wokbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=False
    ActiveCells.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Next i

End Sub
```

I keep recieving the error 13 for mismatched data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have an extra ")" after *.xlsx, you also need to put a colon after multiselect so alltogether

```
FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename("top 20(*.xlsx),*.xlsx", , "Insert Latest Top 20 Report", "Import", MultiSelect:= True)
```

It is interpreting the multiselect as an undefined variable not a parameter accepting an argument.

Edit: You also had an argument as a string ".xlsx" that needs to be an integer or empty.